# Finding document based on incomplete dictionary in pymongo/MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, python-2.7, pymongo

I am storing time as a dictionary, and I don't exactly care about the hour/minute/second because I want to find every appointment that day.

Obviously (or perhaps non-obviously because I thought it would work at first), finding ('time': {'month': m, 'day': d, 'year': y}) returns no results. I assumed I would have to just match the rest of the dict to regular expressions of [any character, any length], but this is also returning nothing.

```
db.appointments.find({'name': some_name, 'time': {'month': mm, 'day': dd, 'year': yyyy, 'hour': r'.*', 'minute': r'.*', 'second': r'.*'}})
```

Everything I've looked up and tried myself doesn't appear to work, either, so I'm not sure what I'm supposed to be doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically, you're storing time as a [subdocument](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/read-operations/#read-operations-subdocuments)
Relevant quote to help you:

> Equality matches for specific fields within subdocuments select
>   documents when the field in the subdocument contains a field that
>   matches the specified value.
>
> In the following example, the query uses the dot notation to match all
>   documents where the value of the field producer is a subdocument that
>   contains a field company with the value 'ABC123' and may contain other
>   fields:
>
> db.inventory.find( { 'producer.company': 'ABC123' } )

So your example may work as:

```
db.appointments.find({'name': some_name, 'time.month' : mm, 'time.day': dd, 'time.year': yyyy}})
```